# Django Fast Access for Time Series Data

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm  working on a web application with **Django & PostgreSQL** as Backend tech stack.

My models.py has 2 crucial Models defined. One is **Product**, and the other one **Timestamp**.
There are thousands of products and every product has multiple timestamps (60+) inside the DB.
The timestamps hold information about the product's performance for a certain **date**.

```
class Product:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AmazonProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=POSSIBLE_STATES, default="St.Less")
    budget = models.FloatField(null=True)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=17, choices=PRODUCT_TYPES, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=325, null=True)    
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children")

   



class Timestamp:
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=35, choices=ADTYPES, blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AmazonProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    spend = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sales = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    acos = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cost = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cpc = models.FloatField(default=0)
    orders = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ctr = models.FloatField(default=0)
    impressions = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    conversion_rate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

I'm using the data for a **dashboard**, where users are supposed to be able to view **their products** & **the performance of the products** for a certain **daterange** inside a **table**. [image]

For example, a user might have **100 products inside the table** and would like to view **all data** from the **past 2 weeks**. For this scenario, I'll describe the code's proceedure below:

- 1. Make call to the backend / server
- 2. Server has to filter & aggregate all Timestamps for each Product
- 3. Server sends data back to client
- 4. Client updates table values

The **problem** is, that **step 2.** takes a **huge amount of time**, and I do not know how to **improve the performance**.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(name="example")
for product in products:
   product.report_set.filter(date_gte="2021-01-01", date__lte="2011-01-14").aggregate(
      Sum("clicks"), 
      Sum("cost"),
      Sum("sales"))
```

That is how the server is currently **retrieving the timestamp values** for the displayed products.
Any ideas how to **retrieve & structure the data** in a **more efficient** way?

Comment: The models you've pasted here don't specify a `report_set` related name for products. (`timestamp_set`, implicitly, yes.) Furthermore there's no field named `daterange` either – it's very hard to help if you don't show us what you're actually working with.

Comment: Additionally, that date field you have should really be a `DateField` or a `DateTimeField`, and beyond that it should be indexed.

Comment: @AKX thanks for the comment. Does an Index need to be unique? Because many Timestamps will have the same date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slow because of the multiple queries you need to make to the database (in the loop).
See if grouping and annotating is better(one query then perhaps queries for fetching each product):-

```
Timestamp.objects.filter(daterange=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-15"]).values('product').annotate(sum_clicks=Sum("clicks")).annotate(sum_cost=Sum("cost")).annotate(sum_sales=Sum("sales"))
```

I don't know if this is possible but if it is it would be even better:-

```
Timestamp.objects.filter(daterange=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-15"]).values('product').annotate(sum_clicks=Sum("clicks")).annotate(sum_cost=Sum("cost")).annotate(sum_sales=Sum("sales")).select_related('product')
```

**Edit**:-
After looking back perhaps this might be better:-

```
products = Product.objects.filter(name="example", report_set__daterange=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-15"]).annotate(sum_clicks=Sum("report_set__clicks")).annotate(sum_cost=Sum("report_set__cost")).annotate(sum_sales=Sum("report_set__sales"))
```

Answer (score -2):

Without more detail all i can recommend is to optimize, for database optimization i would follow the instructions listed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/optimization/) but know as you speed up the query there will likely be an increase in memory usage.